# Rails3 cannot create nest model with has_one DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use Rails3.2.8 to do some practice, here is my models:

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :user, :status, :reference, :location
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location

  validates_presence_of :location, :user, :category


end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :street
  belongs_to :incident
end
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Incident do
  before (:each) do
    @user = create(:user, :name => "user1")
    @incident_data = {:category => "House Break in", :user => @user,
                      :location => {:latitude => "-28.1940509", :longitude => "28.0359692",
                                    :street => "abc name"}}
  end
  describe "After create Incident successfully" do
    it "should create location" do
      incident = Incident.create(@incident_data)

      expect(incident.location.latitude).to eq("-28.1940509")
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to do is to create Location object automatically when creating Incident object. But the test failed by the following reason:

Failure/Error: incident = Incident.new(@incident_data)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:

Location(#70156311891820) expected, got Hash(#70156307112200)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It explicitly says that location should be an instance of `Location`, not a `Hash`. You have

```
:location => {:latitude => "-28.1940509", :longitude => "28.0359692",
                                :street => "abc name"}
```

But as soon you are using nested attributes, it should be `location_attributes` (see [NestedAttributes docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)):

```
:location_attributes => {:latitude => "-28.1940509", :longitude => "28.0359692",
                                :street => "abc name"}
```

or you can just create `Location` object

```
:location => Location.new(:latitude => "-28.1940509", :longitude => "28.0359692",
                                :street => "abc name")
```